# Batch Delete PDF Elements

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, batch-processing

I have several 700+ page manuals split into "chapters". I need to delete the cut marks that the design house put into the files before I can then crop the pages to 8.5x11.

The issue is that doing this manually will takes AGES and I don't have time to hand process that high of a volume.

[Here is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMeSf.png)

The action wizard doesn't have options to use the edit text and images feature of the pdf tools so I'm kind of stuck how to move onward.

Is there a JavaScript that could accomplish this?

Comment: Why did you tag batch scripting twice in this question when you ask nothing about or using CMD?

Comment: @Arescet - the [batch-file] and [batch-processing] tags are completely different. [batch-file] is for the language and [batch-processing] is for manipulating multiple files. The real question here is why the [javascript] tag wasn't used.

Comment: yeah, i saw batch-file and was lost as its the language i expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is some chance that you can get rid of those marks using an according Preflight Fixup (you will need Acrobat Pro for that).

Another possibility would be cropping just a little bit smaller than the cropmarks.